# Objective C Function is not calling up in swift Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using both Objective c and swift in my project. While accessing one function of singleton class of objective c in my swift class, it is not accessible while others functions are accessible.

```
    I am writing my code below for both objective-c (.m,.h) and for swift classes.
```

Code for .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString* apiKey;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UIColor* panelColor;

+(id)sharedTools;
-(void)showProgressHud:(UIView *)view;
-(void)setApiKey:(NSString *)apiKey;
-(void)setPanelColor:(UIColor *)panelColor;
-(void)showProgressIndicator;
-(void)hideProgressIndicator;
-(void)hideProgressHud;
-(void)updateDeviceInformationWithDeviceToken:(NSString*)devicetoken;
- (void)prepareDeviceInformation;
-(void)getCurrentLocation;
```

Code for .m:

```
@implementation Constants

@synthesize location_Manager;

+ (id)sharedTools {
    static Constants *tools = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        tools = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return tools;
}

- (void)setApiKey:(NSString *)apiKey {
    if (apiKey) {
        _apiKey = apiKey;
    }
    else {
        _apiKey = @"";
    }
}

- (void)setPanelColor:(UIColor *)panelColor {
    if (panelColor) {
        _panelColor = panelColor;
    }
}
```

In .swift:

```
 ref?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapShot:DataSnapshot) in
                let apiKeySnapshotResponse = snapShot.value as! [String:Any]
                if NSRUtilities.isNilOREmptyDictionary(apiKeySnapshotResponse) == false {
                    let apiKey = "\(String(describing: apiKeySnapshotResponse["key"]))"
                     (Constants.sharedTools()as AnyObject).setApikey(apiKey:apiKey)
                    OUSTConnectionManager.shareInstance().setApikey(apiKey:apiKey)
```

While this is the function which is working fine in swift class.

```
func configuringCourses(){
        weak var weakSelf = self
        (Constants.sharedTools() as AnyObject).showProgressIndicator()
        let userKey = self.signInUserDetails["studentKey"] as! NSNumber
        let userCourseKey = 
 IMERLANDINGPAGE_URL.replacingOccurrences(of: "{userKey}", with: String(describing: userKey))
        let courseURL = "\(FIREBASE_URL)\(userCourseKey)/course"
        ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: courseURL)
```

Help me out with this.
P.S: Other functions of objective c are accessible.

Answer (score 1):

`+ (id)sharedTools` and `Constants.sharedTools() as AnyObject` is your problem.

`id` in Objective-C is bridged to Swift's `Any` type. So returning any when you know what the response type will be is causing the issue.

Change:

```
+ (id)sharedTools
```

To:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedTools
```

This will return the type as Constants and the auto completion will know which type to lookup. There is a good explanation of why to use `instancetype` instead of the class name in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020540/why-is-instancetype-used)

**EDIT**:

Using the other (current answers) anytime you use `Constants.sharedTools` in Swift you will need to type the class name twice:

```
(Constants.sharedTools() as! Constants).apiKey = "123"
```

If you use `instancetype` in your objective-c class you dont need to cast the type as it returns the right type in the first place:

```
Constants.sharedTools().apiKey = "123"
```

Comment: removing the anyobject throws following error: "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'setApikey'"

Comment: No change , it remained the same. I am using other functions, they are working fine with ID and Anyobject but only this one is giving issue.

Comment: yes, I changed it in .h and .m. This is the code which is working fine.

Comment: func configuringCourses(){
        weak var weakSelf = self
        (Constants.sharedTools() as AnyObject).showProgressIndicator()
        let userKey = self.signInUserDetails["studentKey"] as! NSNumber
        let userCourseKey = 
 IMERLANDINGPAGE_URL.replacingOccurrences(of: "{userKey}", with: String(describing: userKey))
        let courseURL = "\(FIREBASE_URL)\(userCourseKey)/course"
        ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: courseURL)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170687/discussion-between-k-kishore-and-scriptable).

Answer (score 0):

Actually its the casting to `Constants` as the answer of @Sh_Khan:

```
(Constants.sharedTools() as! Constants).apiKey = "123"
```

I tested it.

> Because its a property setter. you set the value with equal.
>
> While a no property method can get called with function indicator `()`

Comment: good spot on removing the set part of setApiKey. returning instancetype is still a better solution than forcing a cast to a type though. Why would you want to use a static type where you have to type the name and also type it again with `as! Constants)` everytime it is used.

Comment: I agree, I changed the setter and change the function name from setApiKey to makeApiKey. Swift has some own predefined functions which names as setValue and etc. So it was not accessing setApiKey. Although, I changed the id to instance type.

Answer (score -1):

Don't cast it to AnyObject put cast it as class name

```
(Constants.sharedTools() as AnyObject)
```

to

```
(Constants.sharedTools() as Constants)
```

Comment: casting it to Constants is giving error:"Value of type 'Constants' has no member 'setApikey'"

Comment: you have to set apiKey directly