# Using Objective-C Singleton in Swift file within Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-swift-bridge

I've got my project written in *Objective-C*. I am learning about bridging.

I bridged successfully *Swift* into my *Objective-C* project. I did some **VC** pushing between *Objective-C* **VC** and *Swift* **VC**. Everything works as it supposed to.

However, I created the reference to my *Objective-C* **NetworkManager** (I used Singleton pattern) in my *Swift* file like that:

```
let networkManager = NetworkManager.sharedManager()
```

For some reason I cannot use methods from it.

```
networkManager.getUserInfo() // .getUserInfo() will not appear!
```

Just to show you how I've created my NetworkManager as a Singleton. I found that solution online and it was quite old, if you have any better solution, I would be more than happy to get some insight:

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static NetworkManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        someProperty = @"Default Property Value";
        self.cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Not sure what is the issue here. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may look for the answer in the future.

I've been advised to not use id type when bridging with Swift. I've changed:

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
```

to

```
+ (NetworkManager *)sharedManager
```

And now everything works fine.

Comment: See [Why is instancetype used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020540/why-is-instancetype-used)